# Create block scoped variable using var keyword in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecma

I want to create a block scoped variable in javascript using **var** keyword. 
 I don't want to create using **let** keyword [ecma6](/questions/tagged/ecma6). As it will not support all browsers.
Is there a way to achieve this through some best and generic way?

> usecase: I want to use this in for loop so that for every iteration it will create a new scope.

Comment: Use shims/pollyfills, babel to transpile ES6 into ES5.

Comment: Yeah Pollyfills will achieve that. I could not find it in MDN. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let Can we do it through core javascript?

Comment: In most situations you can use `.forEach()`.

Comment: @zeroflagL yeah I know that.. But I am curious to find a way to convert function scoped variable to block scoped.

Comment: Blocked scoped variables are only possible with `let` or `const`. Everything else is only a workaround and most of the time also more complex than `forEach`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a "block" with an IIFE like so:

```
(function () {
  var x = "whatever";
  // x is scoped to only within this "block"
  // block code
})()
```

For use in a for loop to maintain scope:

```
for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  (function (i) {
    var x = "whatever";
    // x is scoped to only within this "block"
    // block code
  })(i)
}
```

Comment: You mean "IIFE". Are you suggesting replacing all blocks with functions? So `if (x){var ...}` becomes `(function(){if (x){var ...}}())`?

Comment: @RobG - That's what the transpilers usually do.

Comment: @PitaJ IIFE will do. But I want to use this in for loop. So that for every iteration it will create a new scope. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Oh, and I see @RobG, you've edited your comment. In the case of an `if`, the block is *inside*, so the IIFE would be inside the `if` block if you want to replicate `let` behavior

Comment: @PitaJ Here you are passing var i as a parameter. It is not creating new scope. Even though it does the job, I curious to know the way to create a new scope.

Comment: @PJagajitPrusty - It does create a new scope. The `i` parameter does not refer to the same identifier as the `i` variable outside the IIFE. If you were to rename the `i` parameter of the function, you would see that is the case. Keeping the names the same is done simply for convenience.

Comment: _"That's what the transpilers usually do"_ Only if necessary.

Comment: @PitaJ—but `for (var i ...)` is different to `for (let i ...)`.

Comment: @PitaJ "that's what the transpilers usually do". No it's not.

Comment: @RobG - yes, that's what the IIFE inside the for loop is for. It creates a new scope for each iteration. And yes, this is what the transpilers do. They pull the function out, so it isn't created on each iteration. [This Babel example](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Cstage-2&code=for%20(let%20i%3D0%3B%20i%20%3C%203%3B%20i%2B%2B)%20%7B%0A%20%20settimeout(()%20%3D%3E%20console.log(i)%2C%20100)%3B%0A%7D)